# calling a custom field value inside functions.php

Tags: php, functions, shortcode

I am creating a function, for a shortcode that I will use directly in the post content (using `[my_description_number]` shortcode), and it works, but I do not manage to call (echo or print) a custom field value.

this will not print the custom field value, maybe you know how to make it work? just to print the value of custom field `song_number` when the shortcode will be called

many thanks

````
function wpb_description_shortcode( $atts ) : string {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    
  <?php if (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'song_number', true)) { ?> 
  <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'song_number', true); ?><br/>
  
  <?php } else { ?>   <?php } ?> 

    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
// Register shortcode
add_shortcode('my_description_number', 'wpb_description_shortcode');```
````

Comment: Are you calling this function within the loop?

Comment: I am calling it in the post content, through the shortcode, when adding a post in the WordPress admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're not planning on adding much html there is no need to use `ob_start`  just return the php:

```
function wpb_description_shortcode( ){
    
    if (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'song_number', true)) { 
        return get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'song_number', true).'<br/>';
    } else {
        return;
    }

}
// Register shortcode
add_shortcode('my_description_number', 'wpb_description_shortcode');
```

I'm not sure what this data is, but it would be a good idea to sanitize it too for security.

If you're planning on adding more fields you could do it like this:

```
function wpb_description_shortcode( ){
    $output = '';
    if (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'song_number', true)) { 
        $output .= get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'song_number', true).'<br/>';
    } 
    if (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'another_field', true)) { 
        $output .= get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'another_field', true).'<br/>';
    }
    //random html
    $output .= '<h3> cool html </h3>';
    if (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'even_another', true)) { 
        $output .= get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'even_another.', true).'<br/>';
    } 
    return $output;
}
// Register shortcode
add_shortcode('my_description_number', 'wpb_description_shortcode');
```

Comment: thanks! I am adding more html, and I'm also trying to add more than one custom fields there. I tried to adapt to your code, but when adding more custom fields it will give a fatal error. any way to add more than one custom field? and between them I have some html

Comment: I used echo and it worked, I could add more custom fields. so your answer solved it. much appreciated!

Comment: added other fields and a some random HTML @vyperlook